# recovering a deleted DOCX file

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

So I accidentally deleted a file for school. When i tried using EaseUS recovery thing and Disk Drill I got a file that started with ~$ and word is refusing to open. After finishing the document I saved it. Is there any way to recover it? Some of my other deleted files have autosaves in another directory, but not this document. Please help

Comment: Not in the disk, Not autosaved — You've lost the file :(

Comment: How can I check? I might have got an autosave...

Comment: Go in Word, `File > Options > Save` and Check what the `AutoRecover File Location` is

Comment: `I got a file that started with ~$` .. you might be able to scrape the ASCII from whatever is left of the file.  Try opening it using Word's "recover text from any file".  `File` -> `Open` -> Double click "This PC".  In the file types dropdown, choose "Recover text from any file".  You might get lucky, you might not.